# Calculus 2: Area in Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus, area, polar-coordinates

The graph of $r = 10\cos(3\theta)$ has three petals (also called "leaves" or "lobes").

The intersection of one of those petals with the circle $r = 5$ is shaded in the figure.

That shaded region has area (blank) square units.

[image: Petal Figure]

After attempting this problem, I found the area to be

$A_1$(petal)-$A_2$(intersecting circle)$ = \displaystyle\int_0^\frac\pi 6 10\cos^2(3\theta)\,d\theta-\int_0^\frac\pi 9 (10\cos^2(3\theta)-5^2)\,d\theta$.

However, the website I'm using is telling me that my answer is incorrect.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong with this problem and what the correct answer is?

A big thank you in advance to anyone who is willing to help  out.

Comment: You really need to format your writing if you want anyone to check its correctness.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website and I'm not really sure how to

Comment: @EKM [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is  a quick tutorial and reference on how to use MathJax.

Comment: Thank you my friend

Comment: The area is given by $$\frac 12 \int_a^b r^2 \mathrm d\theta$$

Comment: I simplified it by finding the area of half of the petal and circle to make the lower parameter of the integral 0, and then multiplied the entire integral by 2 which negates the 1/2

Answer (score 0):

When $x\in [\frac {\pi}{9},\frac {\pi}{6}]$ the curve for the "rose" is entirely inside the the circle, and the equation of the circle is ultimately irrelevant in calculating the area of the red region.

[image]

The shaded region for the first half petal is:

$\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{9}} \frac 12\cdot 5^2 + \int_{\frac {\pi}{9}}^{\frac {\pi}{6}} \frac 12 (10\cos 3\theta)^2 \ d\theta$

And remember when you find $r^2(\theta)$ you need to square the coefficients, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is correct, except that the $10$ should be squared along with the cosines in both integrals.